# Umbraco xmltree update dll

Tags: dll, umbraco

I had to change the xmltree.cs file and now i need to move the dll of the compiled code into another project to update the project. There are a ton of dlls in the presentation bin. I wanted to know if anyone would know which specific ones would need to be moved.
Thanks,
Corey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have created your project from the Umbraco source, you will need to get a clean set of the source (same version) and compile it *without* your change. Then make your change and recompile. The affected DLLs will have changed their modified dates, and these will be the ones that are dependent on your code change.

You should never base your project directly on the source, especially if you don't know what you're doing. If you need to modify the source, keep it separate (and under source control) and build your project on the compiled version.